# Video not playing in Chrome - blank white screen

Tags: html, video

URL for site: http://www.humaninterestgroup.org/

We have a provider who has built the site. My partners built this with a third party provider. I am no longer deep enough on HTML to solve this problem.

There is a DIV element with a video playback element. The video loads and plays in in Edge and IE, but not in Chrome. I have verified on two separate laptops that video isn't playing on Chrome.

I thought it was poorly formatted HTML without a type tag for "video/mp4" but using developer console to edit that didn't seem to fix.

The site is hosted in MoPro. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the video a fullscreen video at the beginning? It works in Chrome Win10 very well. https://imgur.com/a/JfExG

Comment: That's the video - if you are watching it all the way through. It's not loading on one Lenovo Yoga, nor on a Surface Book, both on Windows 10.

Comment: What version of chrome did you test this on?

Comment: Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) on both

Comment: The video is working fine for me in chrome 62